# Previous version of Caffe compatible with cuDNN v2

Tags: github, caffe, cudnn

I am trying to locate the last version of Caffe that was still compatible with cuDNN v2.  The current master requires cuDNN v3.  I've been searching through the github repository for Caffe trying to locate what I need but there doesn't seem to be a clear way of doing this.  Is there a relatively painless way of finding this on github ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of [Caffe release](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/releases), and [rc2](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1849) is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I needed.